# unable to run Mysqldbcopy on Suse Enterprise 11

Tags: python, mysql

When I tried to run mysqldbcopy utility I get the following error.

```
mysqldbcopy --source=root:root@localhost:3306 \
          --destination=root:root@localhost:3306 first:first_copy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/mysqldbcopy", line 24, in <module>
    from mysql.utilities.common.tools import check_python_version
ImportError: No module named mysql.utilities.common.tools
```

1. I have checked that python (2.6) is installed on my machine.
2. I have installed mysql python connector mentioned at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/
3. I have installed mysql utilities from 
   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/

I am not sure why I am still getting that error.

Comment: locate the mysql/utilities package and add that path to PYTHONPATH environment variable

Comment: Check if there's an **__init__.py** file under **/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/**; if not, try to `# touch /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mysql/__init__.py`